# How to Authenticate user in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, authentication

I have SQL Database with all my users. I want to use default login page of ASP.NET 4 WebSite Template. What should I change if user is past validation?

This is my Login button

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userName = LoginUser.UserName;
    string password = LoginUser.Password;

    DBAccess dba = new DBAccess();
    DataTable dt = dba.GetUser(userName, password);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Session["UserID"] = dt.Rows[0]["UserID"].ToString();
        string name = dt.Rows[0]["FirstName"].ToString() + " " + dt.Rows[0]["LastName"].ToString();
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);

    }
    else
    {
        LoginUser.FailureText = "Wrong Password or User Name";
    }
}
```

How to change `HeadLoginStatus` and how to set Authentication to True?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To log user in,use this:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName,yourRememberMeCheckBox.Checked);
```

Comment: Thank you. By the way, check my own Answer=)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I realized, that Log in will work with any methods, that redirect you to another page. So I could use next variations:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName,yourRememberMeCheckBox.Checked);
```

Or

```
Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
```

Or

```
Server.Transfer("Default.aspx");
```

All the time you will authorize user

Comment: Of Course you can take Url where to redirect from Query string before.

Comment: first one create cookie and other needed things for auth,but last twos only redirect or transfer you!and if last twos works is `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);` but first have built in redirect